# Core-Data willSave: method

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have an attribute `modificationDate` in my `Entity A.` I want to set its value whenever `NSManagedObject` is saved. However, if i try to do that in `NSManagedObject` `willSave:` method, i get an error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to process pending changes before save.  The context is still dirty after 100 attempts.  Typically this recursive dirtying is caused by a bad validation method, -willSave, or notification handler.' ***
```

So, i'm wondering, what's the best way to set the value of `modificationDate`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From the NSManagedObject docs for willSave:

> If you want to update a persistent property value, you should typically test for equality of any new value with the existing value before making a change. If you change property values using standard accessor methods, Core Data will observe the resultant change notification and so invoke willSave again before saving the object’s managed object context. If you continue to modify a value in willSave, willSave will continue to be called until your program crashes.
>
> For example, if you set a last-modified timestamp, you should check whether either you previously set it in the same save operation, or that the existing timestamp is not less than a small delta from the current time. Typically it’s better to calculate the timestamp once for all the objects being saved (for example, in response to an NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification).

So maybe something along the lines of:

```
-(void)willSave {
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    if (self.modificationDate == nil || [now timeIntervalSinceDate:self.modificationDate] > 1.0) {
        self.modificationDate = now;
    }
}
```

Where you can adjust the 1.0 to reflect the minimum delta between your expected save requests.

Comment: you need to also check if modificationDate is in the changedValues

Answer (score 48):

In fact the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html) (which are only half read in the accepted answer) don't recommend this method. They explicitly say you should use NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification. An example might be:

```
@interface TrackedEntity : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate* lastModified;
@end

@implementation TrackedEntity
@dynamic lastModified;

+ (void) load {
    @autoreleasepool {
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: (id)[self class]
                                                selector: @selector(objectContextWillSave:)
                                                    name: NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification
                                                  object: nil];
    }
}

+ (void) objectContextWillSave: (NSNotification*) notification {
   NSManagedObjectContext* context = [notification object];
   NSSet* allModified = [context.insertedObjects setByAddingObjectsFromSet: context.updatedObjects];
   NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"self isKindOfClass: %@", [self class]];
   NSSet* modifiable = [allModified filteredSetUsingPredicate: predicate];
   [modifiable makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(setLastModified:) withObject: [NSDate date]];
}
@end
```

I use this (with a few other methods: primary key for example) as an abstract base class for most core data projects.

Comment: I like! Was just looking for something like this - appreciate the sample code. Do I need to call [load super]? (Suspecting no if NSManagedObject or its parent does nothing with it.)

Comment: OK! I tried this, and it seems to be too overzealous (or more likely I'm misusing it). I have a managed object that uses lastModified (via MYAPPTrackedManagedObject, basically TrackedEntity above). However, this object contains relationships to other objects that do _not_ use lastModified. Thus, setLastModified: will not be recognized by those other objects, and an exception is thrown. Perhaps I need to dial it back a bit somehow?

Comment: Ahh, maybe just walk allModified and filter out anything that doesn't respond to setLastModified:, and use that.

Comment: I edited the answer to include the filter for you. I don't call [load super] and have no (noticeable) problems, it can't really hurt though...can it? :)

Comment: Why do you do this in `+load` and not `+initialize`?

Comment: +load is called when the runtime loads the class - ie: guaranteed to be called before a context update is made. +initialize is called the first time a class is accessed. Just to make sure all notifications are caught, I use +load.

Comment: I've been trying to figure it out, but I cant seem to; Why did you use the `@autoreleasepool`? any advice?

Comment: load is called when the class is added to the ObjC runtime. This is usually before the all-enclosing @autoreleasepool that is found in the main.m file. If you don't have an autoreleasepool setup, objects will leak.

Comment: so the `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification` occurs before any object validation? this is something i found unclear from the docs

Comment: Shouldn't the predicate be `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"self isKindOfClass: %@", self]`, because here `self` is `TrackedEntity`?

Answer (score 9):

Actually a much better way than the accepted answer would be to use primitive accessors, as suggested in [NSManagedObject's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/willSave)

`

```
- (void)willSave
{
    if (![self isDeleted])
    {
        [self setPrimitiveValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"updatedAt"];
    }
    [super willSave];
}
```

`

Also, check whether the object is marked for deletion with `-isDeleted`, as `-willSave` gets called for those too.

Comment: The docs mention this about overriding willSave: "If you change property values using primitive accessors, you avoid the possibility of infinite recursion, but Core Data will not notice the change you make."

Comment: @PietroRea is it going to be saved to database?

Answer (score 8):

There are obviously several good solutions to this question already, but I wanted to throw out a new one that worked best for one particular scenario I encountered.

(In Swift:)

```
override func willSave() {
    if self.changedValues()["modificationDate"] == nil {
        self.modificationDate = NSDate()
    }

    super.willSave()
}
```

The reason I needed this is because I have the peculiar **requirement of needing to sometimes set the modificationDate manually**. (The reason I sometimes set the time stamp manually is because I try to keep it in sync with a time stamp on the server.)

This solution:

1. Prevents the infinite willSave() loop because once the time stamp is set, it will appear in changedValues()
2. Doesn't require using observation
3. Allows for setting the time stamp manually

Comment: interesting. we are trying to avoid using any client timestamps for anything critical on the server. the devices clock is untrustworthy maybe cause out-of-order errors in sync algorithms. (it's common to store a 'lastSynced' value on the client and use it to ask the server for only those objects that have changed).

Comment: @Sam, I'm using this for data in which the user editing it has the *authority* to resolve merge conflicts. Although I don't provide a UI for resolving, so I just use the time stamps to automatically resolve the conflicts. Since the user has the authority over this data, is does not bother me that their clock might be wrong. It may bother my user, but they will probably also be bothered my missing their appointments and such :). But your point is valid, and I don't think I would employ this method for publicly owned data.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 solution which is a combination of zmit and Richard answer without the need of recurring to `NSNotification`:

```
override func willSave() {
    let expectedNewValue = "Your new value"
    if customField != expectedNewValue, changedValues()[#keyPath(Entity.customField)] == nil, !isDeleted {
        customField = expectedNewValue
    }
    super.willSave()
}
```