# Calculated persistent property in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have properties **firstName** and **lastName** in NSManagedObject class. I need another property **uppercaseFirstLetter** which is calculated from these two. Property **uppercaseFirstLetter** can't be transient and it will be using for sectionNamedKeyPath

```
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest: fetchRequest 
                                    managedObjectContext: [DatabaseManager context]
                                      sectionNameKeyPath: @"uppercaseFirstLetter" 
                                               cacheName: nil];
```

and for sort descriptor

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortLastNameDescriptor = 
[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"uppercaseFirstLetter" 
                            ascending: YES 
                             selector: @selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
```

This is code for calculating uppercaseFirstLetter:

```
NSString *aString = nil;
NSString *lastName = [self valueForKey:@"firstName"];
NSString *firstName = [self valueForKey:@"lastName"];

if (lastName.length) {
    aString = [lastName uppercaseString];
} else if (firstName.length) {
    aString = [firstName uppercaseString];
} else {
    aString = @"#";
}

NSString *stringToReturn = [aString substringToIndex:1];
```

How i need to create **uppercaseFirstLetter** and what changes in code should do to attain this result?

Comment: Did you look at adding a custom setter method? Or what other methods on `NSManagedObject` could help?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874193/core-data-willsave-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom setter methods for `firstName` and `lastName` to update the `uppercaseFirstLetter` property:

```
- (void)setFirstName:(NSString *)firstName
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"firstName"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:firstName forKey:@"firstName"];
    [self updateUppercaseFirstLetter];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"firstName"];
}
```

You also have to do this for `lastName`.

Or you observe changes for `firstName` and `lastName` via KVO to update `uppercaseFirstLetter` if needed. There are many solutions out there how to solve this. Keywords: "NSManagedObject" "KVO"

The last solution might be the more elegant way.