# Using a dirty flag with Core Data for synchronizing with a server

Tags: xcode, core-data, synchronization, magicalrecord

I am working on syncing data between the client and a server. I am using `MagicalRecord` (a Core Data wrapper) for storing the data on the client. I have an entity called `Dirty` that contains a single attribute called `dirty`. This represents if there were changes on the client that have not been pushed up to the server yet. `dirty` gets set to `[NSDate date]` anytime an attribute is set on the class (of course, when setting `dirty`, the correct value is set). Every other entity created on the client inherits from `Dirty`. The idea is that we won’t fetch new data from the server until all client data has been pushed up (only fetch new data if all entities have `dirty == nil`).

When importing data from the server (using `+[NSManagedObject MR_importFromObject:inContext:`), each entity’s `dirty` attribute gets set to `nil` (because the client is up-to-date with the server).

Right before a save is kicked off (inside the `+[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:completion:]` save block), `dirty` is still `nil`. However, in the completion block, fetching the entity that was just saved (on the main thread) has a value for `dirty`.

During the save, the entity is transferred to the main thread’s context. However, there is a problem because `-[NSManagedObject didChangeValueForKey:]` gets called for every attribute that is transferred from the `localContext` (background thread) to the main context (on the main thread). `dirty` gets set with `[NSDate date]` for each entity. Most of the time, `dirty` does not get set last, which means when another attribute is set, `dirty` is overwritten.

Is there a way to make sure `dirty` is the last attribute that is set when transferring the NSManagedObject instance to the main thread’s context? I’m even willing to set `dirty` when the object is saved (instead of when the properties are set).

I’ve tried all sorts of options, including checking against `-[NSManagedObject isInserted]` and `-[NSManagedObject isUpdated]` inside `-[NSManagedObject didChangeValueForKey:]`. One other thing that is kind of annoying is that the new object is inserted before the attributes are transferred over (I thought I could have some sort of flag to lock/unlock setting `dirty`).

Another thing to note is `[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _updateFromRefreshSnapshot:includingTransients:]` is what gets called right before `-[NSManagedObject didChangeValueForKey:]` is called on the new object.

Any ideas? I’ve been facepalming over this for a couple days now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wasting a ton of time on potential solutions, I went back to take a look at solving this issue in the simplest way possible. Here is what I came up with:

1) Deleted `-[Dirty didChangeValueForKey:]`

2) Created a `BTCoreDataService` class, and added the following methods:

```
+ (void)saveClientChangesWithSaveBlock:(BTLocalManagedObjectContextBlock)saveBlock
                       completionBlock:(MRSaveCompletionHandler)completionBlock {
    [self saveAndSetDirty:[NSDate date] 
                saveBlock:saveBlock 
          completionBlock:completionBlock];
}

+ (void)saveServerChangesWithSaveBlock:(BTLocalManagedObjectContextBlock)saveBlock
                       completionBlock:(MRSaveCompletionHandler)completionBlock {
    [self saveAndSetDirty:nil 
                saveBlock:saveBlock 
          completionBlock:completionBlock];
}

#pragma mark - Internal

+ (void)saveAndSetDirty:(NSDate *)dirty
              saveBlock:(BTLocalManagedObjectContextBlock)saveBlock
        completionBlock:(MRSaveCompletionHandler)completionBlock {
    [MagicalRecord
     saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
         if (saveBlock) {
             saveBlock(localContext);

             [[localContext BT_insertedAndUpdatedAtObjectsKindOfClass:[Dirty class]]
              makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setDirty:) withObject:dirty];
         }
     }
     completion:completionBlock];
}
```

And here is the implementation for `NSManagedObjectContext+BTManagedObjectContext`:

```
- (NSSet *)BT_insertedObjectsKindOfClass:(Class)cls {
    return
    [self.insertedObjects
     filteredSetUsingPredicate:[self BT_isKindOfClassPrediate:cls]];
}

- (NSSet *)BT_updatedObjectsKindOfClass:(Class)cls {
    return
    [self.updatedObjects
     filteredSetUsingPredicate:[self BT_isKindOfClassPrediate:cls]];
}

- (NSSet *)BT_insertedAndUpdatedAtObjectsKindOfClass:(Class)cls {
    return
    [[self BT_insertedObjectsKindOfClass:cls]
     setByAddingObjectsFromSet:[self BT_updatedObjectsKindOfClass:cls]];
}

#pragma mark - Internal

- (NSPredicate *)BT_isKindOfClassPrediate:(Class)cls {
    return [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self isKindOfClass:%@", cls];
}
```

The only thing now is to remember to use `BTCoreDataService` to save objects instead of using `MagicalRecord` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the answer from Paul de Lange in SO [10723861](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10723861/529243)

The 'TrackedEntity' over there would be your `Dirty` entity and the attribute `lastModified` would translate to your attribute 'dirty'

During a save (triggered by observing the `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification`) the `-objectContextWillSave` method will merge the inserted objects and the updated objects into a set. Then it goes through the set of object and updates the `lastModified` attribute with the timestamp.

--- Update (wrt. `clientUpdatedAt`)

You might want to look [at this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5052208/529243), too. It explains on how to use some extra fields  to assist with synchronization. Using an extra attribute `sync_status` should help in identifying if a entity needs to be uploaded. Hope that helps

Comment: So I am already doing this with `clientUpdatedAt` (and `clientCreatedAt`). `clientUpdatedAt` is not a good enough indication because when the server updates the entity on the client with the server's `updatedAt`time, the entity has to save and `clientUpdatedAt` is updated with `+[NSDate date]` once again. If I check if `clientUpdatedAt` is more recent than `updatedAt`, it will return `YES` every time. :/

Comment: I have updated my answer, you might need to introduce more attributes to handle synchronization

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. The challenge is this step: `set sync_status to 1 on your model object whenever something changes and needs to be synchronized to the server`. This is the same challenge I am having in my code. I tried using `didChangeValueForKey:` but this wasn't reliable for the reasons I mentioned in my original post. Do you have any suggestions for how to accomplish this step? Once this is figured out, everything else will be smooth sailing.

Comment: I'm thinking about holding onto the dirty value inside the save block, and in the completion block making sure the values are the same. If not, then I will set them again and just save them on the main context. This is getting pretty nasty though.